# How to get the name of array in JSON using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath

Given a Json object or a Json array that contains a Json array inside, I need to return the name of the array itself, without specifying the value inside the array.
In the code, given JSON, and Jsonpath from user, I need to return the name of the array.
Example- given this JSON:

```json
{
  "Contract details": [
    {
      "type": "regular",
      "Details": [
        {
          "Name": "Josh",
          "Country": "USA"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Jake",
          "Country": "UK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to find if the array block "Details" exists within the JSON.
Right now, in order to verify its existence, the user need to specify the full Jsonpath to a value inside the block, which is time consuming, like this:

```
$.Contract details[0].Details[?(@.Name== 'Josh')]
```

This is where I get the jsonPath result in the code, and where I want to verify afterwards the existence of the array object.

```
//json and jsonPath are given strings     
Object jsonObjectType =  JsonPath.read(json, jsonPath);
```

I want to verify that "Details" array block exists, maybe by a short effective JsonPath, or some other way in the code, given json as string.